# Proper way to use copy_to_user?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I'm trying to define a system call that modifies the character buffer passed to it. Specifically, something like this:

```
...
asmlinkage int sys_mycall( char __user *buff, int len )
{
   char tmp[1000];
   copy_from_user(tmp, buff, len);
   /* change tmp here */
   copy_to_user( buff, &tmp, len );
}
```

Here, copy_to_user returns -1, and the buffer from the calling program is unchanged. What's happening?

Comment: The first thing I as a user would do is call the following:
char buf[2000];
sys_mycall(buf, 2000);
What should happen?

Comment: 1000 is strictly greater than length.

Comment: Furthermore, the actual code has error checking.

Comment: Can you show the userspace code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: how can it be used to copy to buff[index] of userBuff ? [index != 0]
copy_to_user( buff+index, &tmp, len );

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks OK.  It's possible that the buffer that userspace passed is mapped read-only - for example if it's in the text segment (eg. a string literal).  By the way, this is probably what you want:

```
return copy_to_user(buff, &tmp, len) ? -EFAULT : 0;
```

Comment: The actual code does do that. I simplified the example to illustrate the core issue.

Comment: I abhor C. Your answer fully solves my problem, but I refuse to admit why.

Comment: I think someone forgot to sign their errno :)

Answer (score 8):

Remeber that tmp is already a pointer!
Correct way to do it:

```
copy_to_user( buff, tmp, len );
```