# How to use 'copy_to_user'?

Tags: linux

I have to add a system call in linux kernel that will print the process tree showing only the PIDs to user code. I have to use copy_to_user here. But I am not understanding the use of this function. Could any of u give an example of how it works, including the user-side code and added system code?.....Any easy/simple example would be great for me...:)
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper way to use copy_to_user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1836585/proper-way-to-use-copy-to-user)

Comment: http://www.gnugeneration.com/mirrors/kernel-api/r4299.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read through the Linux Device Driver book. It's freely available online at http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/. Although it's geared towards device drivers, it covers most of the key aspects for communicating between kernel and user space and includes multiple examples.

By the way, this sounds like a homework question. If so, your question should have the 'homework' Tag associated with it.